# Error al descrifrar cifrado cesar php

Tags: php

Teniendo este código

**Cesar.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Programa: Cifrado Cesar-->
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Cifrado Cesar</title>


    <head>

    <body>

        <h1>Calculadora Simple</h1>


        Mensaje a descifrar
        <form action="resultado.php" method="post">
        <select name="cifrado">

            <option value="cifrar">Cifrar</option>

            <option value="descifrar">Descifrar</option>

        </select>   

</select><br/>
           <!–  Introducimos el texto a descrifrar ->

            <label for="texto">Texto a descrifrar o descifrar</label>
            <input type="text" name="texto"><br />

            <label for="desplazamiento">desplazamiento</label>
            <input type="number" name="desplazamiento"><br />


            <!–  Borrar los valores ->
            <label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>    
            <input type="reset" value="Borrar">

            <!–  Recoger los datos ->
            <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
            <input type="submit" name="Enviar">

        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Y este otro código, no me funciona la opción de descifrar:

**resultado.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
function cesar($texto,$clave){
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($texto);$i++){
        $texto[$i]=chr(ord($texto[$i])+$clave);
    }
    return $texto;
}

if ($_POST["texto"] != ""&&$_POST["cifrado"] != ""
    && $_POST["desplazamiento"] != "" ) {

    if ($_POST["cifrado"] == "cifrar") {
        $cifrado=cesar($_POST["texto"],$_POST["desplazamiento"]);

    } elseif ($_POST["cifrar"] == "descifrar") {
        $cifrado=cesar($_POST["texto"],-$_POST["desplazamiento"]);
       echo("Hola");
    }



    echo $texto."<br>";
    echo $cifrado."<br>";
    print ('<br /><a href="cesar.php">Volver</a> ');
}
?>
```

No entra en el descifrado y muestra solo el volver

Comment: Te salta algun error en alguna linea? Supongo que `$_POST["texto"] != ""&&$_POST["cifrado"]` estará separado y ahora esta junto al poner el código aquí.

Comment: Tienes un signo menos cuando llamas la función cesar en descifrar, antes de la variable $_POST("desplazamiento"), ya revisaste eso? si es un número que debe ir negativo deberías multiplicar por -1

Comment: Tienes mal escrito el nombre de la variable, pones cifrado y cifrar. Por eso no entra en ese elseif

Comment: te sugiero revisar: https://code.sololearn.com/wOl61a2F297E/#php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un error al recibir los datos. Te lo pongo como comentario en tu propio codigo. Estás recibiendo el select, pero en la comprobación de descifrar has puesto cifrar, en lugar de cifrado, por lo que falla al recibir y nunca entrará dentro del descifrar, porque cifrar, como elemento del dom, no existe.

```
error_reporting(0);
function cesar($texto,$clave){
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($texto);$i++){
        $texto[$i]=chr(ord($texto[$i])+$clave);
    }
    return $texto;
}

if ($_POST["texto"] != ""&&$_POST["cifrado"] != ""
    && $_POST["desplazamiento"] != "" ) {

    if ($_POST["cifrado"] == "cifrar") {
        $cifrado=cesar($_POST["texto"],$_POST["desplazamiento"]);

    } elseif ($_POST["cifrado"] == "descifrar") { //En tu código original ponias cifrar al recibir el post y es cifrado
        $cifrado=cesar($_POST["texto"],-$_POST["desplazamiento"]);
       echo("Hola");
    }

echo $texto."<br>";
echo $cifrado."<br>";
print ('<br /><a href="cesar.php">Volver</a> ');
```

Modificando esto debería funcionar tu código. Nos cuentas que tal.